# How to customize polynomial print in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have polynomials which coefficients are computed using numerical integration methods. Mathematically, I use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to produce orthogonal polynomials from a given probability distribution function, which involves integrals in the associated Hilbert space. Hence, they are sometimes approximated as floating point numbers very close to zero, although I know that the mathematical value is zero. I would like to customize the printing so that these values are not printed at all.

For example, the script:

```py
import numpy as np
p = np.polynomial.Polynomial([1.23456789e-15, 1.0, 1.23456789e-13, 2.0])
print("p = ", p)
```

produces:

```
p =  1.23456789e-15 + 1.0·x¹ + 1.23456789e-13·x² + 2.0·x³
```

but I would like to print:

```
p =  1.0·x¹ + 2.0·x³
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at the `np.polynomial.Polynomial.__str__` method code (which formats this print string), but it may be overly complicated for your needs.  I don't see parameters that would tell it to omit the 0 coefficient terms.  (converting your near zeros to zeros is easy).

Answer (score 1):

The best I managed to come up with is editing the funcion output, removing numbers that are to small and reformating:

```
coeffs = p.coef
formatted_coeffs = []
for i, coeff in enumerate(coeffs):
    if abs(coeff) >= 1e-5:
        formatted_coeffs.append("{:.1f}·x^{}".format(coeff, i))
print("p = ", " + ".join(formatted_coeffs))
```

This code prints what you wanted:

```
p =  1.0·x^1 + 2.0·x^3
```